# Verify Magento With Solr Search

Tags: magento-enterprise, solr, magento-ee

If I search any keyword through the website , it's showing me the data but when I search the same keyword via Solr panel, most of the times showing no data .

I try to search using SKU , which is 100% working fine.

Is my Magento working with Solr search perfectly ?

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento Version 1.14.2.1

Comment: It's better if we open new ticket in Magento EE portal.

Comment: Solr configuration is ok , During indexing time i check that Solr is adding data. Please read my problem again.

Comment: I question if i am not able to find the keyword in Solr , how my web can show the result .

Comment: <str name="fulltext_1_en">
014000001 Corona DS238HV Digital Metal Gear Servo 4.6kg / 0.13 Sec / 22g
</str>
<str name="id">59</str>
<bool name="in_stock">true</bool>
<int name="position_category_2">10001</int>
<str name="sku">014000001</str>

When i search by SKU , i got that result but when i search by Product Keyword : Corona , no result